# PHP every nth div

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I need to have few different size divs on my site and I'm printing classes with simple PHP loop now. First it works fine for few first divs but after that it doesn't work.

Here is the situation I want

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small special"></div>
    <div class="small special"></div>
    <div class="large"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small special"></div>
    <div class="large"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="large"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="large"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
</div>
```

And from there on it continues using that same pattern as last 2 rows. So basically the large div moves from right to left on each row. Special divs comes from out of loop. Here's my current php:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small special"></div>
     <div class="small special"></div>
    <?php while loopstuff here ?>
    <?php 
        if ( $i == 0 || $i == 1 || ($i %3) == 0 ) : 
            $size = "large";
        else :
            $size = "small";
        endif; 
    ?>
    <?php if ( $i == 1 ) : ?>
        <div class="small special"></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $size; ?>"></div>
    <?php if ( $i == 0 || $i == 2 || ($i % 3) == 0 ) : ?>
        </div><!-- .row -->
        <div class="row">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $i++; ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
</div>
```

First two rows works fine but rows after that prints either one col in row or two. So my problem is with this ($i % 3) == 0 ) i believe.

Answer (score 0):

Customizable working prototype:

```
<?php
    $iTotalRowCount = 10;
    for( $i = 0; $i < $iTotalRowCount; ++$i )
    {
        $aPositions = array();
        if( ( $i % 3 ) === 0 )
        {
            $aPositions = array( 'small', 'small', 'large' );
        }
        else if( ( $i % 3 ) === 1 )
        {
            $aPositions = array( 'small', 'large', 'small' );
        }
        else if( ( $i % 3 ) === 2 )
        {
            $aPositions = array( 'large', 'small', 'small' );
        }
        $iCountPositions = count( $aPositions );
        for( $k = 0; $k < $iCountPositions; ++$k )
        {
            echo '<div class="' . $aPositions[ $k ] . '">' . $aPositions[ $k ] . '</div>';
        }
        echo '<br />';
        echo 'Set end.';
        echo '<br />';
    }
?>
```